# Create a Trigger to genearate a random alphanumeric string in informix

Tags: informix

To create a trigger before insert using Informix database.
When we try to insert a record into the table it should insert random alphanumeric string into one of the field. Are there any built in functions?

The table consists of the following fields:

- `empid serial NOT NULL`
- `age int`
- `empcode varchar(10)`

and I am running

```
insert into employee(age) values(10);
```

The expected output should be something as below:

```
 id age empcode
 1, 10, asf123*
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In Informix there are no built in functions to generate random strings. You will have to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented there is no existing function to create a random string however it is possible to generate random numbers and then convert these to characters. To create the random numbers you can either create a UDR wrapper to a C function such as `random()` or register the excompat datablade and use the `dbms_random_random()` function. 
Here is an example of a user-defined function that uses the `dbs_random_random()` function to generate a string of ASCII alphanumeric characters:

```
create function random_string()
returning varchar(10)
define s varchar(10);
define i, n int;
let s = "";

for i = 1 to 10
  let n = mod(abs(dbms_random_random()), 62);
  if (n < 10)
  then
    let n = n + 48;
  elif (n < 36)
  then
    let n = n + 55;
  else
    let n = n + 61;
  end if
  let s = s || chr(n);
end for

return s;
end function;
```

This function can then be called from an insert trigger to populate the empcode column of your table.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the response  I created trigger and called the above functionas below
create trigger rand_trigtest
INSERT ON employeetest
FOR EACH ROW(EXECUTE FUNCTION random_string() INTO empcode)
iam getting dbms_random_random cant be resolved.we will try to install the following package,and can u let us know how the above function works

Comment: @P.S.Mahalakshmi — The `+48` converts values `0..9` into digits `'0'..'9'` (which have code points `48`..`57` in ASCII (and Unicode, and ISO 8859, etc).  The `+55` could be regarded as `- 10` (to allow for the 10 digits) and `+ 65` where `65` is the ASCII code for `'A'`; it converts codes 10..36 into letters A-Z).  And the `+61` could be regarded as `- 36` (ten digits, twenty-size upper-case letters) and `+ 97`, where `97` is the ASCII code for `'a'`; it converts codes 37..63 into letters a-z.

Comment: Hi,we have implemented the above trigger in one of our environment and facing the below issue.
please find the error when application tries to call a post api as below:

Comment: 2019-05-06 10:39:02 ERROR    [Informix_Conn.py : 37] QRY001 error in query : INSERT INTO dots.project_organization_map
        (project_guid, org_guid, project_manager_uid, project_start_date, project_end_date,
        cretaedby_empid, createdby_timestamp, last_updatedby_empid, last_updated_timestamp,project_name)

Comment: VALUES('a234e3b4-1319-11e9-87d3-6a0ba69fbc52', 'pGkFc4niJ6', '0469B4744', '2018-11-08', '2019-10-31', 'AVL2UA744', current, 'AVL2UA744', current, 'calimtest0001');
2019-05-06 10:39:02 ERROR    [Informix_Conn.py : 43] DB001 : Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][IDS/UNIX64] Unique constraint (informix.project_organization_map_pk) violated. SQLCODE=-268

Comment: Please find the table definition as below:
CREATE TABLE testdb:dots.project_organization_map (
 orgprojectguid varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 project_guid varchar(50),
 org_guid varchar(50),
 project_manager_uid varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 project_start_date date NOT NULL,
 project_end_date date NOT NULL,
 cretaedby_empid varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 createdby_timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
 last_updatedby_empid varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 last_updated_timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
 project_name varchar NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (orgprojectguid) CONSTRAINT project_organization_map_pk
) ;

Comment: Please find the trigger code as below:
create  trigger testdb:dots.project_organization_map_trig
INSERT ON dots.project_organization_map
FOR EACH ROW(EXECUTE FUNCTION random_string() INTO orgprojectguid);

Comment: Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: Hi,
After 3 insertions the next value is a duplicate hence we are getting unique constraint violated.
Also the string doesnt contain any numeric values
please find the sample strings it generated:
OpCWiWsgul
W6PjTHxUQp
kHLCKX4FtZ
and after the next insertion we are getting the error
Please help in resolving this

Comment: The sample strings do contain numeric values (6 and 4) but not purely numeric values since the requirement was for an alphanumeric string. 
As for the unique constraint error the most likely reason is that the random number function used is only a pseudo-random number generator and needs to be seeded. Use the function dbms_random_initialize() with an integer argument to seed it. The integer value needs to take on different values so for example you could use the session id as returned by dbinfo("sessionid").